# Unable to start mongod with one missing collection wt file

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I have a working mongod instance (v3.2.21).

But suddenly it stopped working. When i run mongo command it is throwing me following error:

```
2019-06-04T13:52:41.725+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
```

When i checked log its showing:

```
2019-06-04T13:36:43.388+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (2) [1559655403:388180][8404:0x7fb74e904c80], file:collection-1-1305830686620002691.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /mnt/volume-fra1-01//collection-1-1305830686620002691.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2019-06-04T13:36:43.388+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] no cursor for uri: table:collection-1-1305830686620002691
2019-06-04T13:36:43.388+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Invalid access at address: 0x58
2019-06-04T13:36:43.398+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

The collection which was earlier there is now missing in data directory

I tried to use --repair but the process gets stop at this collection.

I have looked at various resources but couldn't figure out how to make it working?  Is there way so that wiredtiger escape this collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoD 4.0.3 and newer has better repair facilities as per [SERVER-19815](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19815).

One thing you can try:

1. Copy your original `dbpath` so if the attempt is not successful, you don't clobber your original data
2. Download the 4.0.3 binaries (or newer, currently the latest is 4.0.10)
3. `mongod --repair` using the 4.0.3 binaries to attempt to repair the copied `dbpath`
4. If the repair is successful, try to run the 3.2.21 binaries pointing to the repaired `dbpath`

Please note that this repair attempt is best-effort and there's no guarantee of success. Having an up-to-date backup is still recommended. You might also want to investigate how the `dbpath` is missing a file to begin with.

Comment: right now i have 300gb of data and only 170gb unused space, that means i have to add additional space to copy dbpath. Can you please provide me links/documentation where i can find how to install 4.0.3 binary without interfering 3.2 binary.

Comment: If you're using Linux or Unix, you can use https://github.com/aheckmann/m to install multiple versions of MongoDB

Comment: i was able to complete the recovery process. But now 3.2 binaries are unable to read the 4.0.10 binaries updated db files. txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 3/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

Comment: i am also getting 2019-06-06T05:34:16.632+0000 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.

Comment: i have downgraded to 3.4 and the mongod service started